# periodic task for celery sent but not executed

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks, celery

I am using `celery` in one of my `django` projects to perform some tasks. I recently required to add a `periodic_task` to update a field for the objects in one of my models. so I added a `periocdic_task` as follows.

```
import datetime
import logger.logger as logger

from celery.decorators import periodic_task



@periodic_task(run_every=datetime.timedelta(seconds=30))
def entries_about_to_expire():
   """ Changes the status of entries that are about to expire.
   """

   try:
       import entries.models as models
       startdate = datetime.datetime.today()
       enddate = startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
       soon = models.EntryStatus.objects.get_or_create(
               name='Expiring Soon')[0]
       models.Entries.objects.filter(expiry_date__range=[startdate, enddate])\
               .update(status=soon)

   except Exception, err:
       logger.exception("Error while changing job status: %s" % (err))
```

Next thing I did was to run `celery` as follows:

```
>>python manage.py celeryd -l info --beat
```

Everything runs fine until now. I can even see the task is sent by celery as follows (this happens every 30 seconds as required).

```
[2013-11-15 15:01:10,690: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task entries.tasks.entries_about_to_expire (entries.tasks.entries_about_to_expire)
```

But for some reason the task is not executed. I mean I can't find any changes in the `status` of `Entries` objects. I tested this using the shell.

```
In [2]: from entries.models import Entries, EntryStatus

In [3]: soon = EntryStatus.objects.get_or_create(name='Expiring Soon')[0]

In [4]: entries = Entries.objects.filter(status=soon)

In [5]: entries
Out[5]: []
```

I get the same results even after the task is sent multiple times. I am sure the code for `entries_about_to_expire` runs fine because if I call it manually it works. For example if I do the following in the shell

```
In [6]: from entries.tasks import entries_about_to_expire

In [7]: entries_about_to_expire()

In [8]: entries = Entries.objects.filter(status=soon)

In [9]: Entries
Out[9]: [<Entries: 223>, <Entries: 512>, <Entries: 526>, <Entries: 591>]
```

**So why is the celery task is not executing ? any clues ?**

*Note: I've also tried the `celerybeat_schedule` method but the same results i.e. task is sent but not executed*

Comment: @AndreyNelubin Yeah, this was resolved, I don't exactly remember how I resolved it but the problem was with the broker instance. I ran celery with a few options (don't really remember which ones) to make sure the tasks are being sent to the correct broker.

Comment: any solution?     .

Comment: In my case I was missing the --result-backend param from the worker & beat commands eg. `celery -A webapp -b redis://localhost:6379/0 --result-backend redis://localhost:6379/1 worker --loglevel=INFO`